# How to copy HTML tags to clipboard without changes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery) SO answer to copy page content using pure JavaScript on user click. However my content contains HTML tags:

```
<script>http://localhost:3000/widget/174b6b69bcf352803a00</script>
```

When pasted from the clipboard it turns into this:

```
&lt;script&gt;http://localhost:3000/widget/174b6b69bcf352803a00&lt;/script&gt;
```

How can I revert it back?

Comment: That because you copied the HTML source as text.

Comment: maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248849/converting-sanitised-html-back-to-displayable-html

Comment: @GolezTrol yep thanks! Changed innerHTML to innerText and all went fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` to get the plain text version without HTML tags in it.

Comment: `innerText` is [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) feature, use `textContent`.

Comment: @FrooeyZanny You're right. Thanks for the addition. There are some differences between innerText and textContent though, which are fortunately well-documented by our friends at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to parse HTML entities :

```js
function parseHTMLEntities(htmlString) {
  var e = document.createElement("div");
  e.innerHTML = htmlString;
  return e.innerText;
}

// use like this :

var text = parseHTMLEntities("&lt;script&gt;http://localhost:3000/widget/174b6b69bcf352803a00&lt;/script&gt;");

alert(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I mistook URI ecoding with HTML entities...

That was a stupid mistake...

see this question:

[How to convert characters to HTML entities using plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript)

Comment: doesn't work, try in the console : `decodeURIComponent("&lt;script&gt;http://localhost:3000/widget/174b6b69bcf352803a00&lt;/script&gt;");`

Comment: @Apolo, really?I'll try it when I can access a PC.

Comment: `decodeUriComponent` decode things like `%3A` etc., not `&lg;`

Comment: @Apolo, you are right. I mistook uri ecoding with html entities.