# how to decode html in div encoded at server side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am using asp.net application. where I have generated JSON at server side in one of node of JSON has html formatted text so I have used httputility.htmlencode();
so on client side I got it as

```
&lt;h1&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #ff0000;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;added general commetns&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
```

and when I trying to render this in Div it is also rendering in above way. instead of that I want to see formatted text without <h1, it should be in way that with applied style.

how could it be possible?

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate question, but here is the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249234/5780021

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

htmlDecode("&lt;h1&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #ff0000;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;added general commetns&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h1&
```

Result is:

```
<h1><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">added general commetns</span></strong></span></h1>
```

Comment: This will not work serverside, as there is no `document`.