# HTML in Json with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

i'm building a App with Ionic that uses AngularJS.
So, with the API on link http://lucassmuller.com/work/projetoblog/api.php?action=posts I want to show the content ('conteudo') of the post in a page of my App but show that like this example:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Voc&amp;ecirc; tem&amp;nbsp;um site e deseja um certificado SSL gratuitamente?&lt;\/strong&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Se a resposta &amp;eacute; sim, eu tenho uma ferramenta que lhe oferece um certificado SSL gratuitamente usando o Let&amp;rsquo;s Encrypt, que &amp;eacute; uma nova&amp;nbsp;&amp;ldquo;Autoridade de Certifica&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o&amp;rdquo; que &amp;eacute; gr&amp;aacute;tis, automatizada e aberta para todos.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;O nome dessa ferramenta &amp;eacute; &amp;ldquo;&lt;strong&gt;SSL For Free&lt;\/strong&gt;&amp;rdquo; ou, em portugu&amp;ecirc;s, SSL gratuito. Este novo servi&amp;ccedil;o &amp;eacute; 100% gr&amp;aacute;tis, e confiado e aceito pela maioria dos navegadores.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Para come&amp;ccedil;ar, basta acessar o site da ferramenta &lt;a href=&quot;https:\/\/www.sslforfree.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;clicando aqui&lt;\/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;e ap&amp;oacute;s o acesso, digitar o dom&amp;iacute;nio do seu site no campo que diz...
```

And the output:

```
Você tem um site e deseja um certificado SSL gratuitamente? Se a resposta é sim, eu tenho uma ferramenta que lhe oferece um certificado SSL gratuitamente usando o Let’s Encrypt, que é uma nova “Autoridade de Certificação” que é grátis, automatizada e aberta para todos. O nome dessa ferramenta é “SSL For Free” ou, em português, SSL gratuito. Este novo serviço é 100%...
```

**Update:** my actual code after changes

*controllers.js:*

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, $filter, API, $http, $stateParams, $sce) {

    var postId = $stateParams.postId;

    function replace_chars(input) {
        return input.replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
      }

    function htmlDecode(input){
      var e = document.createElement('div');
      e.innerHTML = input;
      return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }

    API.posts_all().then(function(response){
        var posts=response.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
          if (posts[i].id == parseInt(postId)) {
            $scope.post = posts[i];
            $scope.post.conteudof = replace_chars(posts[i].conteudo);
          }
        }
        console.log('post get ok');
    });

    $scope.doRefresh = function() {

        API.posts_all().then(function(response){
            var posts=response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
              if (posts[i].id == parseInt(postId)) {
                $scope.post = posts[i];
                $scope.post.conteudof = replace_chars(posts[i].conteudo);
              }
            }
            console.log('post get ok');
        })

     .finally(function() {
       // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
     });
  };

})
```

*tab-post.html:*

```
<ion-view view-title="{{post.titulo}}">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-refresher
      pulling-text="Puxe para atualizar..."
      on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <div class="list card">

      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img src="{{post.gravatarautor}}">
        <h2>{{post.nomeautor}}</h2>
        <p>Postado em {{post.data * 1000 | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item item-body">
        <div ng-bind-html="post.conteudof"></div>
        <!--<p>
          <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
          <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>
        </p>-->
      </div>

    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Problem: it's showing HTML as a raw/plain text.

Comment: Have you tried to use `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: Yes, but shows basically the same thing, :C

Comment: your problem is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248849/converting-sanitised-html-back-to-displayable-html

Comment: I did that [link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/z5ow6) but the content aren't showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's is a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = replace_chars('&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Voc&amp;ecirc; tem&amp;nbsp;um site e deseja um certificado SSL gratuitamente?&lt;\/strong&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Se a resposta &amp;eacute; sim, eu tenho uma ferramenta que lhe oferece um certificado SSL gratuitamente usando o Let&amp;rsquo;s Encrypt, que &amp;eacute; uma nova&amp;nbsp;&amp;ldquo;Autoridade de Certifica&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o&amp;rdquo; que &amp;eacute; gr&amp;aacute;tis, automatizada e aberta para todos.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;O nome dessa ferramenta &amp;eacute; &amp;ldquo;&lt;strong&gt;SSL For Free&lt;\/strong&gt;&amp;rdquo; ou, em portugu&amp;ecirc;s, SSL gratuito. Este novo servi&amp;ccedil;o &amp;eacute; 100% gr&amp;aacute;tis, e confiado e aceito pela maioria dos navegadores.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Para come&amp;ccedil;ar, basta acessar o site da ferramenta &lt;a href=&quot;https:\/\/www.sslforfree.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;clicando aqui&lt;\/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;e ap&amp;oacute;s o acesso, digitar o dom&amp;iacute;nio do seu site no campo que diz...');

  function replace_chars(input) {
    return input.replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div>
    <span ng-bind-html="test"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello again. I did it today but it's showing the html content as a raw text.

Comment: Hello, did you inject the ngSanitize?

Comment: Yes, i did inject.

Comment: Well, strange.. can you make an edit in your post, posting how is your JS/HTML file (just the relevant code)?

Comment: Hello, my post was changed. Please, note the update.

Comment: You didn't inject 'ngSanitize' my friend, as I said: it should be `angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngSanitize'])`. Also you have to put `angular-sanitize` (as I did) in your project.

Comment: It's injected _app.js_ but if I do it, happens the same. And I put the scripts in _index.html_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116893/discussion-between-developer033-and-lucas-muller).