# AngularJS showing html scope as raw text

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm using an API to get my posts of my blog. But i'm getting the content that's a HTML code but i'm trying to see it as i saw in the blog but aren't working.
I had tried it using this filter and functions:

```
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
};
})
```

And in controller:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

In the template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.conteudo | unsafe"></div>
```

But this codes aren't making this work properly. As result of this, i get a raw/plain text like this:
[image]

What can i do?

Comment: Have you injected the filter dependency into the controller for the relevant html template?

Comment: Like this: `.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, unsafe, API, $http, $stateParams, $sce)` ?

Comment: You need to tag on filter. unsafeFilter. Is the filter defined in the same module as the controller?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same module.

Comment: You could try using the filter directly in the controller instead of the html and see if that makes any difference. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller

Comment: I did: `$scope.post.conteudo = $filter('unsafe')(htmlDecode(conteudo));` but it had showed the same thing.

Comment: Does the filter actually get called? Try placing a console log statement inside the filter return function and see what happens .

Comment: It isn't being called. I put the full code (see code after line 97) of my controllers.js at [here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/95mvz) to you see.

Comment: I can't see any problem with the code. Could you post a demo with the html as well? https://plnkr.co/

Comment: Dude, i followed this [snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38172495/6195300) on my another question. The snippet is working but when putted in action or in my code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things. You don't need this filter, as well as `htmlDecode` function. All you need is `$sce.trustAsHtml`:

```
$scope.post.conteudo = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b>Thomas Mann</b>');
```

and in HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.conteudo"></div>
```

```js
 angular.module('demo', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope, $sce) {
   $scope.post = {}
   $scope.post.conteudo = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b>Thomas Mann</b>')
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <div ng-bind-html="post.conteudo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but the 'conteudo' are like this: `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Voc&amp;ecirc; tem&amp;nbsp;um site e deseja um certificado SSL gratuitamente?&lt;\/strong&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Se a resposta &amp;eacute;`. If I do as you said, happens the same: shows the formatted HTML as a plain text.