# ODOO report automatically convert character < as &lt;

Tags: javascript, report, odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I have a character type field which its value sometimes contain `<`,`>` or `&`,
when I use report, odoo automatically convert it as `&lt;`.

I have tired use js export and import to get an external function to convert.
(I can not put this function in view template, because if the template contain <,> or &, python interpreter can't parse file with these characters.)

```js
var convert= function (str) {
return str.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>').replace(/&amp;/g,'&');
                    };


export {convert};
```

this file path is `my_module/static/src/js/js1.js`
And in same module I have a view template import it as:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript">
import {convert} form "/my_module/static/src/js/js1.js"
.
.
.
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
        <t t-esc="doc.surfhrd"/>
.
.
.
```

And get no data since import line is added.

I expect this can convert the html character to its origin appearing.

And I sure this function can work that I have tested in browser's developer tools console.

Comment: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248849/converting-sanitised-html-back-to-displayable-html) is suitable for your purpose?

Comment: I can not put function in template's script directly, so its solution will not work,either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution in [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/qweb.html#setting-variables).

[image]

```js
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
    \\<t t-esc="doc.corehrd"/>
    <t t-raw="doc.corehrd"/>
```

replace `t-esc` as `t-raw`